# How to produce a confidence map in CNN?

Tags: image, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Suppose I have a ground-truth image with every pixel labeled as 0 or 1.Now I'd like to produce a confidence map by CNN.

---

The result of CNN is a confidence map,which every pixel is a value varies from 0 to 1.And if this pixel in ground-truth is 1, its counterpart in result should be 1 or close to 1,vice versa.(that's why I call it confidence map,just as the thermal imagery).
I'm not doing the segmentation work, which produce a probability map as result and use channel-wise max function to get its label.I don't want to do the convert operation,just produce a 1-channel confidence map(thermal map).

[image]

this figure I snatched from a paper in CVPR2018,'Attentive Generative Adversarial Network for Raindrop Removal from A Single Image',just like the blue image in the figure.I don't know if I
can do it using an encoder-deconder network and how to do it.

Comment: What software are you using? Have you made any progress? When you apply a convolution, for example in tensorflow tf.nn.conv2d, you will get an output value for each pixel, for each channel (depending on padding). Each channel can be displayed as heatmap as in the graphic you shared. You could normalise this output to the 0 to 1 range.

Comment: @ziggyjones so I can use any channel solely to produce the confidence map? But there’s another question:how to make it seems like the thermal imagery?Like the image in that figure,it’s not a black-white image,it’s colorful.

Comment: What the channel will represent is not defined in most networks and will depend on how the network is trained. If you want the channel to represent something specifically you would need to train it for that purpose. I'm not familiar with that paper but you could try looking at one of the later CNN outputs. You can plot color representations with a number of tools, for example matplotlib.pyplot.

Comment: You can plot any image with any numeral range to look like thermal image... But then it is a vastly different question than the one you are asking.